# Taking screenshot in robot framework on step (keyword) failure

Tags: robotframework

I am  testing a GUI application with robot framework and AutoItLibrary. I would like the test to take screenshot after any failure in test, but not in the test teardown, but right after the error occurs, as the steps in between the failure and the teardown usually make the screen worth nothing. Is there a way to do that in robot? All I could get so far is a screenshot in the end of a test...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt lib has CaptureScreenOnError (defaults to False) argument so when importing the lib, set it to True. See https://robotframework-autoitlibrary.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-AutoItLibrary-1.1/doc/AutoItLibrary.html

It will not take screenshot if the error happens in non-AutoIt lib keyword. AFAIK there isn't any nice and sure way to take screenshot after any failure.

```
Run Keyword If Test Failed    Take Screenshot
```

in every test teardown will handle most situation, but if the error happens in a keyword that has a teardown, the keyword teardown will be done before the test teardown. And "Run Keyword If Test Failed" will only work in test teardown.

Comment: Thanks Harri, I have spent so much time on that page lately, and failed to see that argument. I'll try it in action and see if it's what I was looking for.